# Tastypie - Counting failed and succeeded requests

Tags: django, tastypie

Let's assume I have the following resource (example from tastypie cookbook http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#creating-per-user-resources):

```
class EnvironmentResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Environment.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'environment'
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        # maybe even some validation
        validation = FormValidation(form_class=forms.EnvironmentResourceForm)

    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
       return super(EnvironmentResource, self).obj_create(bundle, user=bundle.request.user)
```

Now I want to use `statsd` client (https://github.com/jsocol/pystatsd) to count occurrences of http status codes (or just to count 2XX and 4XX/5XX separately). But I have no idea where exactly I should put my code, either `statsd.incr('success')` or `statsd.incr('failure')`. Do you have any suggestions?

Or maybe you know other ways to count http status codes? (I don't want to analyze access logs).

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Maybe I should define a new middleware (like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/messages/middleware/) which would be resolved as the last one. The counters would be increased in `process_response` method.

Answer (score 1):

You could override the `dispatch()` method. Something like:

```
def dispatch(self, request_type, request, **kwargs):
    # do something with request_type and request.status_code
    return super(EnvironmentResource, self).dispatch(self, request_type, request, **kwargs):
```

Comment: Thank you, it will work :) However, a middleware can handle wider range of requests. In fact, if a middleware is declared at the top of django middlewares, it handles also messages rejected by other middlewares (e.g. an authorization middleware).

Comment: Actually, I think the authorization is handled after dispatch, but I could be wrong. You could solve it with a middleware as well. I guess you can use `request.status_code` and `request.META['REQUEST_TYPE']`. And you could also filter out urls that are not part of the API